# Accessing an IAP protected API from a localhost frontend

Tags: google-iap

I often develop in a local React SPA and want to use an IAP protected backend API. The backend API is only IAP protected in dev, in production everything is open.

Currently the only solution I can think of involves a mostly transparent nginx proxy running locally that takes a users credentials and constantly does programmatic IAP Auth and attaches the appropriate cookies/headers to all requests. So a kind of Identity aware 'proxy proxy'.

I don't want to add IAP code to the react app, because IAP is only for development. I'm surprised no one has made anything like this yet though (I couldn't see anything on GitHub), does the approach sound valid?

Comment: I realise as I write this that this nginx setup won't be able to popup a browser and have the user negotiate authentication

If I could have IAP issue domain wide cookies instead of just subdomains that would help a lot, but is there a reason this isn't possible?

Comment: Otherwise my "best case" now is a little binary i'll write that does the IAP flow in a browser window and stores the cookie/refresh token in a file, then nginx gets configured to check those files and run the refresh token flow if necessary

Comment: Did you find any other solutions? I'm basically going to be doing something similar I think. We use: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware and it allows us to pass customer headers, I think I'll just pass in an IAP token in there behind the scenes.

Comment: Nope this is the way I went in the end, a 'run-this.sh' that embeds some credentials and a local proxy reading that creds file. It's transparent to our application. Really poor as a solution though, I feel unclean. We didn't want to leave API tokens lying around but I think for the pain it's caused that would have been a better solution. That obviously means issuing one per engineer and aggressively managing it e.g. if they leave the company deleting it at the same time as their other details.